# Custom authentication: how to get custom user data values?

Tags: android, android-authenticator

I have custom authenticator.
And put account information like it shown below:

```
final AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(AuthActivity.this);
final Bundle result = new Bundle();
final Bundle userData = new Bundle();
userData.putString(KEY_NAME, mName);
userData.putString(KEY_EMAIL, mEmail);

Account account = new Account(mLogin, vcs.getAccountType());

if (am.addAccountExplicitly(account, null, userData)) {
    result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME, account.name);
    result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_TYPE, account.type);
    result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN, mAccessToken);
    result.putString(KEY_REFRESH_TOKEN, mRefreshToken);
    am.setAuthToken(account, account.type, mAccessToken);
} else {
    result.putString(AccountManager.KEY_ERROR_MESSAGE, "F@ck|n8 authenticator");
}

setAccountAuthenticatorResult(result);
setResult(RESULT_OK);
finish();
```

But how I can get these custom values when I need it?

I try to get it so:

```
tvUsername.setText(accountManager.getUserData(account, AuthActivity.KEY_NAME));
tvEmail.setText(accountManager.getUserData(account, AuthActivity.KEY_EMAIL));
```

What I do wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Check out [Android AccountManager.getUserData() returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28691847/android-accountmanager-getuserdata-returns-null/29776224#29776224). There is a known issue with `addAccountExplicitly`. Instead of passing the values in the Bundle, pass an empty Bundle and set the values after creating the account using [setUserData(Account, String, String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html#setUserData%28android.accounts.Account,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29).

IIRC, the problem is a caching issue in the account manager service code. If you remove an account and recreate the same account right away the user data cache in not populated with the values passed in the bundle. Using `setUserData` works around this issue.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about this bug.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the actual bug?

Comment: Sorry, I can't. I never searched for a bug report, nor did I file one. My findings were to vague to create a substantiated bug report. However, we've never seen any issues like that with `setUserData`.